# Block website during maintenance except for testers

Tags: redirect, admin, maintenance-mode

I would like to block the access to my website while I make changes to it. But I want some selected people and myself to have access to do tests. I found this method which is good (http://25yearsofprogramming.com/blog/20070704.htm), except for the fact it is based on ip addresses (I don't know the ips of everyone and can't ask).

How can I do the following:
- redirect all urls to a page like maintenance.php
- on that page, there is a form that people can use to enter a code
- if the code is valid, the redirection stops and they have access to the website normally

Thanks

Comment: Why not just have a separate instance of the website for testing?  Then you wouldn't need to do this, and the test would be a closer match to production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont want to use ip addresses you can setup htaccess with passwords for the your testers and everybody else will be redirected.

This site can help you with that: http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/password/

Comment: That works thanks! Except there was a "Password Mismatch" error. I used this website (http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/) instead to generate the password and now it is all good.

Comment: Your welcome if you need further assistance this is the place to ask.